# DuplicateNameException using DataSet ReadXmlSchema

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, xsd

I get ***DuplicateNameException*** when I try read XSD file using `ReadXmlSchema`.

```
this.Schema = new DataSet();
this.Schema.ReadXmlSchema(this.SchemaFile);
```

**The error:**

> System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named 'Tipo' already
>   belongs to this DataTable.

**full xsd file:** https://gist.github.com/kiquenet/86090779650975b7426a7f798174eef6#file-respuesta-xsd

**StackTrace:**

```
   en System.Data.DataColumnCollection.RegisterColumnName(String name, DataColumn column)
   en System.Data.DataColumnCollection.BaseAdd(DataColumn column)
   en System.Data.DataColumnCollection.AddAt(Int32 index, DataColumn column)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleElementColumn(XmlSchemaElement elem, DataTable table, Boolean isBase)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node, XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node, XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node)
   en System.Data.XSDSchema.LoadSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, DataSet ds)
   en System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlSchema(XmlReader reader, Boolean denyResolving)
   en System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlSchema(String fileName)
```

Any suggestions for fix it or get more information about the cause of error?